# find percentile of a value.. ecdf returning a value that looks strange

Tags: r

With this data set: https://pastebin.com/qWgMZDDb

I'm trying to find the percentile of the last value of the `5daychange` column.

I run:

```
ecdf(dat$daychange5)(tail(dat$daychange5, 1))
# returns 0.05056554
```

Which is saying that the last value would be in the 5th percentile, or 95% of all observations are greater.

However if I plot the data this doesn't look quite right:

```
last.value = tail(dat$daychange5, 1)

library(ggformula)
library(ggplot2)

gf_dhistogram( ~ daychange5, data = dat, binwidth = 0.01) %>% 
  gf_fitdistr(color = 'red') +
  geom_vline(xintercept = last.value)
```

That verticle line seems higher than the 5th percentile, it looks to be around 10-12?

[image]

edit: sample of data to be safe (although pastebin is set to never expire)

```
structure(list(date = structure(c(18096L, 18099L, 18100L, 18101L, 
18102L, 18103L, 18106L, 18107L, 18108L, 18109L, 18110L, 18113L, 
18114L, 18115L, 18116L, 18117L, 18120L, 18121L, 18122L, 18123L
), class = "Date"), daychange5 = c(-0.0600000000000001, -0.0425000000000002, 
-0.0150000000000001, -0.00249999999999995, 0.0100000000000002, 
0, 0.00250000000000017, -0.00749999999999984, -0.00249999999999995, 
-0.05, -0.0325000000000002, -0.04, -0.0625, -0.0550000000000002, 
0.01, -0.00499999999999989, -0.0700000000000001, -0.0850000000000002, 
-0.11, -0.1225)), row.names = 2992:3011, class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Please provide data with `dput(head(df,n))`. Links might break in the future.

Comment: Why? the last.value is **-0.1225** and it is the minimum value of your data set. Additionally, also it is appearing at the far left of your histogram, so %95 of all observations are greater than  last.value.It makes sense.